# Submit to multiple php scripts

Tags: php, javascript, forms, function, submit

I have a javascript function which I'm using to change the action field of a form and then submit it. Here's the function

```
function printmulti(){
form=document.forms['form2'];
form.action="http://localhost/output_sample1.php/";
form.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window
form.submit();

form.action="http://localhost/output_sample2.php/";
form.target = "_blank";
form.submit();
return true;   }
```

But somehow only output_sample2.php is being shown. Why isn't the first part of the code being executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cant submit to multiple forms like that, you need to use something like ajax and make the requests that way. Currently you are starting the submit for the first and then starting the second right after so the second one stops the first one from submitting.

[Ajax Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/)

Comment: Review your URL, it's invalid

Comment: fixed, weird characters got put in it some how.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax like this:

```
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'http://localhost/output_sample1.php/',
           data: 'var1='+var1+'&var2=var2', //your variables sent as post at output_sample1.php
           success: function( data ) {
//do success stuff
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(status); //if any error
           },
           dataType: 'text'
    });

    $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'http://localhost/output_sample2.php/',
               data: 'var1='+var1+'&var2=var2', //your variables sent as post at output_sample2.php
               success: function( data ) {
    //do success stuff
               },
               error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  alert(status); //if any error
               },
               dataType: 'text'
        });
```

Hope will give you some idea to start your work. For more info visit this link [ajax example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp)

Comment: this uses jQuery, he might not know what jQuery is

Comment: @patrick evans
Well, I just tried the original code in FF, its working fine there! But its not working in Chrome for which I was developing originally. Why is that? If the original code had faults, its shouldn't have worked in FF also.

Comment: good point Patrick Evans. but i m giving him idea. But if he find this problematic i will guide him. what SO is all about

Comment: I was just meaning you may want to add something to the post to point out it was jQuery so him/others will know where to go for jQuery. @RahulSarma do you mean the code here or your code?

Comment: That is just a fluke, FF might have ran the code slower than Chrome allowing for the headers to be sent to the server before being stopped